# In Python unable to access SSH using paramiko with private key and Http proxy

Tags: python, paramiko

*Am using python script to ssh the server with PEM key and its require http proxy type as well for successful connection. But getting lambda error while executing the script.
I have tried the same manually to access the server and its working fine as expected.
Kindly update if there is any alternate module or alternate way to resolve this issue at earliest.*

```
import socket
import paramiko
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock1 = sock.connect(('10.x.x.x', 8080))
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("C:\AccessKey.pem")
ssh.connect('x.x.x.x', port=22, username="admin",pkey=privkey, sock=sock1)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Could you you update your question and provide this lambda error. What line raised the error?

Comment: Am getting below error - File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in connect    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr)) File "C:\paramiko\util.py", line 283, in retry_on_signal return function() File "C:\paramiko\client.py", line 349, in <lambda> retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))